# Hyundai Elantra 1998 Child Restraint Anchors

Tags: safety, hyundai, elantra

Just wondering if anyone has had experience fitting child restraint anchors to a Hyundai Lantra 1998 (or similar)?

I've located the holes for where the anchors should go (according to the manual) but there is physically no way to get in behind the holes to place the backplate for the anchors and the nut. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up having to take it into a vehicle safety place where they installed the bolts for us. Not sure exactly what they did but I think they got in behind somehow and installed a bolt.

Answer (score 0):

Is there not a captive nut already behind the hole? That is certainly the case on a lot of older cars that were not originally fitted with rear seatbelts, so may well be the same for child restraint anchors on newer vehicles